# My composer autoload file don't contain classes

Tags: php, rest, composer-php, autoloader

I'm creating a `REST API` with `PHP` using `Composer` and `coffeecode/datalayer` library but when I'm trying to load my class I receive *Class not found error* and when I type `dump-autoload` on terminal I get *Generated autoload files containing 0 classes*

**composer.json**

```
{
   "name": "bruno_monteiro/restapi_php",
   "description": "Simple PHP REST API",
   "type": "project",
   "require": {
      "coffeecode/datalayer": "1.1.*"
   },
   "license": "MIT",
   "authors": [
      {
          "name": "Bruno Monteiro",
          "email": ""
      }
  ],
   "minimum-stability": "stable",
   "autoload": {
      "psr-4": {
          "Source\\": "source/"
       }
   }
}
```

**Model**

```
namespace Source\Models;

final class Validations{
        ...
}
```

**Controller (where the error occurs)**

```
namespace Source\Controllers;

require "../../vendor/autoload.php";
require "../Config.php";

use Source\Models\Validations;

switch($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]){

case "POST": 
    $data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), false);
    if(!$data){
        header("HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request");

        echo json_encode(array(
            "response"=>"Nenhum dado informado"
        ));
        exit;
    }

    $errors = array();

    if(!Validations::validateString($data->first_name)){

        array_push($errors, "Nome informado inválido");

    }
    ...
```

**Directory structure**

```
│   composer.json
│   composer.lock
│   Script.sql
│
├───source
│   │   Config.php
│   │
│   ├───Controllers
│   │       User.php
│   │
│   └───Models
│           User.php
│           Validations.php
│
└───vendor
    │   autoload.php
    │
    ├───coffeecode
    │   └───datalayer
    │       │   composer.json
    │       │   CONTRIBUTING.md
    │       │   LICENSE
    │       │   README.md
    │       │
    │       ├───example
    │       │   │   db_config.php
    │       │   │   destroy_example.php
    │       │   │   find_example.php
    │       │   │   pdo_example.php
    │       │   │   save_example.php
    │       │   │
    │       │   └───Models
    │       │           Address.php
    │       │           User.php
    │       │
    │       └───src
    │               Connect.php
    │               CrudTrait.php
    │               DataLayer.php
    │
    └───composer
            autoload_classmap.php
            autoload_namespaces.php
            autoload_psr4.php
            autoload_real.php
            autoload_static.php
            ClassLoader.php
            installed.json
            LICENSE
```

Comment: Please show us your directory structure.

Comment: Added to the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved my problem by loading the classes on `dump-autoload` using the `-a` flag